# Jquery remove labels from contact form on focus

Tags: jquery, html, forms, label

I need some help with my contact form. I'm trying to remove the labels automatically when the user clicks in the box, but I can't seem to figure out how.

This is the HTML

```
<div class="six columns">
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="six columns">
                <label class="gfield_label" for="Name" style="display: block;">Name<span class="gfield_required">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="Name" required class="mobile-four" />
            </div>
            <div class="six columns">
                <label class="gfield_label" for="Name" style="display: block;">Company</label>
                <input type="text" id="Name" required class="mobile-four" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="six columns mobile-four">
                <label class="gfield_label" for="email" style="display: block;">Email<span class="gfield_required">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="email" class="mobile-four" id="email" required />
            </div>
            <div class="six columns mobile-four">
                <label class="gfield_label" for="phone" style="display: block;">Phone<span class="gfield_required">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="phone" class="mobile-four" id="phone" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns mobile-four">
                <label class="gfield_label" for="message" style="display: block;">Message<span class="gfield_required">*</span>
                </label>
                <textarea id="message" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="three columns centered">
                <button id="contact-submit-btn" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Contact us Now!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

and this is the JS I have tried so far. But nothing seems to work.

```
$('input, textarea').focus();
    $(this).prev('label').hide();
});


$('.gfield_label').focus(function () {
    $('label.mobile-four[for="' + $(this)[0].id + '"]').hide();
});

$('.gfield_label').each(function () {
    2
    var elem = $(this);
    3
    $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').click(function () {
        4
        elem.focus();
        5
    });
    6
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        7
        $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').hide();
        8
    }
    9
}).focus(function () {
    10
    $('label[for="' + $(this)[0].id + '"]').hide();
    11
}).blur(function () {
    12
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        13
        $('label[for="' + $(this)[0].id + '"]').show();
        14
    }
    15
}).change(function () {
    16
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        17
        $('label[for="' + $(this)[0].id + '"]').hide();
        18
    }
    19
})
```

It would be great if someone could help. The page is at beta.harbordev.com/contact.html

Thanks so much

UPDATE!!!!!

```
$(function() {
    $('input, textarea').on('focus blur', function () {
        $(this).prev().toggle();
    });
});
```

This suggestion kind fo worked. It's live on the website now, but somehow the message field (textarea) always disappears with whatever else is selected and is also gone when nothing is selected. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Did you try wrapping that in a document.ready ?

Comment: @LauraSchoebel  Please edit the type in your subject ;)

Comment: @LauraSchoebel - is there any reason you don't use `placeholder` ? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: Yes, because placeholders are for form explanations (e.g. please only use caps) while lables are for exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('input, textarea').on('focus blur', function () {
        $(this).prev().toggle();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L6gJ7/)

Comment: Your code worked somewhat. Take a look. However the message field always disappears alogn with whatever else is clicked. Can you help fixing that?

Comment: What message fields, and how are they dissapearing exactly ?

Comment: go on beta.harbordev.com/contact.html

Comment: you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

**[Working Deom](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Me4/6/)**

```
$('input, textarea').focus(function(){
      $(this).prev('label').hide();
});
```

Comment: This one made all the labels disappear before I even clicked anything. I mean it's technically a step in the right direction but still not on click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input, textarea').keyup(function(){ 
 if($(this).val()=="")
      $(this).prev('label').show();
 else
      $(this).prev('label').hide();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aRV7q/9/)**

Comment: I tried your code, but unfortunately there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. I assume you're trying to hide the label when a value exists and if it doesn't exist it gets displayed again.

This doesn't rely on your HTML structure which is good if you're not dealing with consistent markup.

```
var $inputs = $(':input'), 
    $labels = $('label');

$inputs.on('input blur focus', function () {

  var $input = $(this),
      value = $input.val(),
      id = $input.attr('id'),
      $label; 

  $label = $labels.filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('for') === id; 
  });

  $label.toggle(value.length === 0);

}).trigger('input');
```

and here is a little demo: http://jsbin.com/jigucuna/4/edit?html,js,output

PS: You may want to look into the `placeholder` attribute as well.